# After working on a machine learning project how do I save it for others to see

Tags: python, machine-learning

please I need your help am a beginner in machine learning after working with your machine learning project how do I send it for others to see please help am using Python

Comment: What exactly do you want to share? the code, the results?

Comment: Please, read [How to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pickle is the standard way of serializing objects in Python.

Let's assume you had some data, you did some preprocessing and fit the model.

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

You can save that model object to the disk as a binary file with pickle.

```
import pickle
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

When you want to use it again, you can reload the model like this,

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

and reuse it again...

```
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, Y_test)
print(result)
```